# how to get purchase infos from in-app-purchases

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

How i can get informations(purchase date, product id...) about purchase made by the user ?

```
switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased: {
            NSLog(@"user has purchased, %@", transaction);
...
...
```

Comment: It would be nice if you stop asking the same question every 10 hours.

Comment: it would be nice if u answer, better than just watching and hide.. !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the related properties:

```
let purchaseDate = transaction.transactionDate
let transactionId = transaction.transactionIdentifier
let produtId = transaction.payment.productIdentifier
```

Comment: Error: Property 'product' not found on object of type 'SKPayment *'

Comment: try: import StoreKit

Comment: transaction[found].payment[found].product[this one no, not found]

Comment: What information do you need from there? Check properties here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpayment

Comment: purchase date & transactionId and product id